Ctrl+w Shift+n after :term does not start a normal window
In Vim, you can start the terminal by :term, and Ctrl+WShift+N allows you to treat the terminal window as a normal Vim window. I tried the same in NeoVim, but it does not work. Is it an expected result? Or what is required in NeoVim to do the same thing as in Vim?

The standard for that action is Ctrl \Ctrl n.
Since on my Azerty keyboard this is difficult to type I have introduced the following mapping:
tnoremap <C-q>  <C-\><C-n>

With that mapping I can switch from Terminal mode to Normal mode with Ctrl q
More information with :help t_CTRL-_CTRL-N
This is supported on both Vim and Neovim.
Remark: Ctrl wShift N seems to br only supported in Vim (I don't find the corresponding help section in Neovim documentation).
